# Multiple Strategy Design Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I want to be able to gather several pieces of validation entities, all sharing same interface. This  is what I came up with:

```
public interface Ivalidateable
{
  bool IsValid(IValidateParam param);
}

public interface IValidateParam
{

}

public abstract EmployeeStrategy: Ivalidateable
{
  public abstract bool IsValid(User user); 
}

public abstract SpreadStrategy: IValidateable
{
 public abstract bool IsAvlid(Campaign campaign);
}

public class User: IValidateParam
{}

public class Campaign: IValidateParam
{}

public EmployeeTypeStragtegy: EmployeeStrategy, IValidateable
{
 public bool IsValid(User user)
 {
  if  (new[]{'e',a','b}.Contains(user.userId.first().toString()))
  return true;

  return false; 
 }
}

public TrailSpreadStrategy: SpreadStrategy, IValidateable
{
 public bool IsValid(Campaign campaign)
 {
  //logic goes here
 }
}

public EvenpreadStrategy: SpreadStrategy:, IValidateable
{
 public bool IsValid(Campaign campaign)
 {
  //logic goes here
 }
}

public class ValidationFactory
{
 private static List<IValidateable> stragtegies;

 static ValidationFactory
 {
  strategies = new List<IValidateable>();
  strategies.Add(new EmployeeTypeStragtegy());
  strategies.Add(new TrailSpreadStrategy());
 }

 public bool IsValid(//Need to pass User/Campaign)
 {
  //what do I do here?
 }
}
```

What is the best way to pass User / Campaign so that I can loop strategies and check IsValid?

Comment: You have two strategies for validating Campaigns, would both be executed or is there some criteria to select the correct one?

Comment: there will be just one of each type (User/Campaign)...I just wanted to show the idea of declaring more than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
// campaign object class, and it's separate validator logic

public class Campaign
{
}

public class CampaignValidator : IValidationStrategy<Campaign>
{
    public bool IsValid(Campaign test)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// framework stuff

public interface IValidationStrategy<T>
{
    bool IsValid(T test);
}

public static class ValidationFactory
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<Type, object> _typeValidators;

    static ValidationFactory()
    {
        _typeValidators = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        _typeValidators[typeof(Campaign)] = new CampaignValidator();
    }

    public static bool IsValid<T>(T obj)
    {
        return ((IValidationStrategy<T>)_typeValidators[typeof(T)]).IsValid(obj);
    }
}
```

After that, you can call `ValidationFactory.IsValid(myObject);` and if the type is in the factory static constructor, it will give you true/false.

The validation factory is doing a kind of DI/IOC thing, i.e. you could use Ninject, Castle etc to achieve mapping a type to a validator type.

You could do things dynamically or differently without having to build the dictionary in the same way - look at the generic type parameter of the interface the validator implements, or search for `IValidationStrategy<>`-based classes and again look at the generic type parameter.  But the above is quick and simple.

Is there a reason you want separate validator classes?

Comment: I wanted to seperate them since each gets a difference object to to the validation

Comment: Yes I see that, but why not include an IsValid on each object itself? :)

Comment: I think i got you! thanks! I want to loop throught them and call IsValid for every Strategy thats why I have IsValid for eachof them.

Comment: btw, how can I validate all the dictionary strategies with a loop in the factory's IsValid , using your suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Chaining)'s nesting and collection validation capabilities. This should work fine without an extra factory and interfaces - if your strategies hold references to the other entities you want to validate along with them.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Change all of your IsValid to use this prototype (User user, Campaign campaign), for example:

```
public EmployeeTypeStragtegy: EmployeeStrategy, IValidateable
{
 public bool IsValid(User user, Campaign campaign)
 {
    return (new char[]{'e','a','b'}.Contains(user.userId.first().toString());
 }
}
```

And then handle each by the appropriate type, that way they all accept the same arguments. and then:

```
public bool IsValid(User user, Campaign campaign)
 {
   bool valid;

   foreach (IValidateable iv in strategies)
   {
      if (!iv.IsValid(user, campaign))
          valid = false;
   }

   // This returns true if all are valid, false if not (not sure if this is the logic you expect)
   return valid;
 }
```

Comment: I want to do something like this: 

    public bool IsValid(User user, Campaign campaign)
     {
       return strategies.All(s=>s.IsValid(//???))
     }

Comment: So you want to provide 1 user and 1 campaign and loop through all strategies to see whether they are valid for either one depending on type?

Comment: Exactly crlangois!!! If the strategy is based on Employee it will use the user, if it is SpreadStrategy it will use the campaign